# debian 11 as router in virtual - doesn't route when connects with a vpn

Tags: linux, networking, router, debian, routing

I installed a vm with the debian 11 with 2 network adapters

Target is, that the vm connects to a VPN and then route all the trafic from the host computer.

`adapters`:

- enp0s8 as bridge
- enp0s3 as Host-only using vboxnet0

[image]

```
root@vm-debian11:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s3
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp

auto enp0s8
allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

```
$ cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

If I say to the host machine the gateway is 192.168.0.17 or  192.168.56.102... works/routes.

My issue is when I connect with the vpn

```
root@vm-debian11:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:42:66:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.17/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 78300sec preferred_lft 78300sec
    inet6 fdaa:bbcc:ddee:0:a00:27ff:fe42:6635/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 2006054619sec preferred_lft 2006054619sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe42:6635/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:f2:39:30 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.102/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global dynamic enp0s8
       valid_lft 464sec preferred_lft 464sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef2:3930/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 172.70.1.2/27 brd 172.70.1.31 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::88ad:cd64:8441:a6ff/64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route after connecting to the vpn

```
~# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3 onlink 
10.0.0.0/14 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
10.8.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
10.9.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
10.10.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
10.11.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
10.164.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
100.64.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
172.20.0.0/15 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
172.31.0.0/16 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
172.40.0.0/15 via 172.70.0.129 dev tun0 
172.70.0.128/27 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 172.70.0.130 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.15 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.16
```

Sounds that trafic is not routing between enp0s8 and tun0

What I am missing ?

Comment: Source NAT, probably.

Comment: What host interface is enp0s8 connected to, what host interface is enp0s3 connected to, why do they have IP addresses from the same subnet? What do you have in your VM's routing table (`ip route`)?

Comment: added requested info to the description. Can I achieve this with only one adapter ?